# DELETE rows with foreign constraints without using "on cascade"

Tags: sql, t-sql, with-statement

I am a newb to SQL since I can normally get away with simple queries/migrations without digging into it, however I have a more complex one that doesn't involve a join and I am wondering how I delete when there is a foreign constraint without using on cascade. Here's my query. I could not find a good answer from googling.

```
WITH aDeleteVariable AS (SELECT TOP 1 FooID as id FROM [BSystem].[Foo].[bar] order by      
CreateTimeUTC desc)
DELETE FROM [BSystem].[Foo].[fooBar] where FooID = id
DELETE FROM [BSystem].[Foo].[bar] where FooID = id
```

So I need to delete [BSystem].[Foo].fooBar first, then [BSystem].[Foo].[bar] This will be executed at run time so it cannot be hard coded. "1" is really going to be n, however I have that code worked out.

I get **invalid column name 'id'** when trying to execute this query. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DELETE` statements don't reference `aDeleteVariable`.  The `id` column only exists in the context of `aDeleteVariable`.

You need to join `aDeleteVariable` into your `DELETE` statements.  Also, you can't reuse the common table expression, so you have to duplicate it.

See this [SQL Fiddle (with simplified schema/table names)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/709f7/2), but below is what you want.

```
WITH aDeleteVariable AS (SELECT TOP 1 FooID as id
        FROM [BSystem].[Foo].[bar] order by CreateTimeUTC desc)
DELETE FB 
        FROM [BSystem].[Foo].[fooBar] AS FB
        INNER JOIN aDeleteVariable AS DV ON (FB.FooID = DV.id);
WITH aDeleteVariable AS (SELECT TOP 1 FooID as id
        FROM [BSystem].[Foo].[bar] order by CreateTimeUTC desc)
DELETE B
        FROM [BSystem].[Foo].[bar] AS B
        INNER JOIN aDeleteVariable AS DV ON (B.FooID = DV.id);
```

Of course, with joining to `aDeleteVariable`, you don't need the `id` alias. The following will work.

```
WITH aDeleteVariable AS (SELECT TOP 1 FooID
        FROM [BSystem].[Foo].[bar] order by CreateTimeUTC desc)
DELETE FB 
        FROM [BSystem].[Foo].[fooBar] AS FB
        INNER JOIN aDeleteVariable AS DV ON (FB.FooID = DV.FooID);
WITH aDeleteVariable AS (SELECT TOP 1 FooID
        FROM [BSystem].[Foo].[bar] order by CreateTimeUTC desc)
DELETE B
        FROM [BSystem].[Foo].[bar] AS B
        INNER JOIN aDeleteVariable AS DV ON (B.FooID = DV.FooID);
```

Given that there are two separate common table expressions, there is a race condition, and the second expression might return a different `FooID` (or multiple when you adapt this to `N` records).  You might want to select your IDs into a table variable instead of using a common table expression.  The following should work.

```
DECLARE @DeleteVariable TABLE (FooID INT);
INSERT INTO @DeleteVariable (FooID)
        SELECT TOP 1 FooID FROM [BSystem].[Foo].[bar]
                ORDER BY CreateTimeUTC DESC;
DELETE FB 
        FROM [BSystem].[Foo].[fooBar] AS FB
        INNER JOIN @DeleteVariable AS DV ON (FB.FooID = DV.FooID);
DELETE B
        FROM [BSystem].[Foo].[bar] AS B
        INNER JOIN @DeleteVariable AS DV ON (B.FooID = DV.FooID);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, however if I replace id with aDeleteVariable, I get the same error message with a different variable name.